# Qt Designer inverting pixels of a QLabel so it's the opposite of the background

Tags: qt, qt-designer

I'm working on a GUI application in Qt Designer and I have a transparent QLabel. Is there any way to make the QLabel the opposite of the background? (Example: If the background is white, the QLabel would be black)

Comment: Is the background a solid color that we know ahead of time? Or could it be something like an image where each pixel could be something different?

Comment: If your are looking for an out-of-the-box functionality to make the text of QLablel visible, regardless of the background, as far as I know, there isn't one. You have to implement it yourself.

Comment: @JarMan the background is an image (set as background image from the stylesheet) that we know ahead of time. It's like a pattern, the colour of it being white, having some grey triangles. Can i make the label show the inverted pixels of it?

Comment: That sounds like something that an OpenGL shader could help with. But I'm not an expert on that.

Comment: @JarMan I was thinking of changing the stylesheet of the QLabel in some way to inherit the background then invert, but I don't know how to do that